# Why isn't a Unity Canvas loading?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I tried to change it to Canvas, but it's still not going to the next scene/canvas.
I already added the `RoomList` in the building settings but still not going there.
It's not reaching the `StartCoroutine(LoadNextSceneWithDelay(3f)); Debug.Log("Login successful.");` part.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;

public class LoginScript : MonoBehaviour {
  public TMP_InputField idInput;
  public TMP_InputField passwordInput;

  public Button visibilityButton;
  public Button loginButton;
  private bool isPasswordVisible = false;

  private Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference databaseReference;

  private void Start() {
    // Set up the Firebase database connection
    databaseReference =
        Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    loginButton.onClick.AddListener(OnLoginButtonClick);
    visibilityButton.onClick.AddListener(OnVisibilityButtonClick);
  }

  public void OnLoginButtonClick() {
    string id = idInput.text;
    string password = passwordInput.text;

    // Check if ID and password are empty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
      Debug.Log("Please enter your ID and password");
      return;
    }

    // Check if ID is empty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) {
      Debug.Log("Please enter your ID");
      return;
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
      Debug.Log("Please enter your password");
      return;
    }

    // Check if connected to the Firebase database
    if (Application.internetReachability != NetworkReachability.NotReachable) {
      Debug.Log("Connected to Firebase database");
    } else {
      Debug.Log("Not connected to Firebase database");
    }

    try {
      // Query the database for the username and password
      DatabaseReference usersRef =
          databaseReference.Child("Users").Child("Monitoring");

      usersRef.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
          Debug.LogError("Error retrieving data from Firebase database: " +
                         task.Exception);
          return;
        }

        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
        bool idFound = false;
        bool passwordMatched = false;

        foreach (DataSnapshot userSnapshot in snapshot.Children) {
          string storedID = userSnapshot.Value.ToString();
          string storedPassword = userSnapshot.Value.ToString();

          if (storedID == id) {
            idFound = true;

            if (storedPassword == password) {
              passwordMatched = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        // Check the results and load the scene or display debug messages
        if (idFound && passwordMatched) {
          StartCoroutine(LoadNextSceneWithDelay(3f));
          Debug.Log("Login successful.");
        } else {
          if (!idFound) {
            Debug.Log("Incorrect username");
          }

          if (!passwordMatched) {
            Debug.Log("Incorrect password");
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Debug.LogError("Exception in OnLoginButtonClick: " + ex.Message);
    }
  }

  private IEnumerator LoadNextSceneWithDelay(float delay) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("RoomList");
  }

  public void OnVisibilityButtonClick() {
    isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
    UpdatePasswordVisibility();
  }

  private void UpdatePasswordVisibility() {
    if (isPasswordVisible) {
      passwordInput.contentType = TMP_InputField.ContentType.Standard;
      passwordInput.ForceLabelUpdate();
    } else {
      passwordInput.contentType = TMP_InputField.ContentType.Password;
      passwordInput.ForceLabelUpdate();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you just mean "Scene".  Nothing to do with "Canvas".  At your line of code "Check the results..." add BEFORE that line, two Debug Log lines to show you the values of idFound and passwordMatched.

Answer (score 1):

First check that the Scene has been added to the Scenes in Build.

[image]

Secondly your `foreach` loop should check that the username and password matches a single entry and in the error output don't put which part was incorrect as that assists bad actors trying to bruteforce accounts.

```
bool loginSuccess = false;

foreach (DataSnapshot userSnapshot in snapshot.Children) {
  string storedID = userSnapshot.Value.ToString();
  string storedPassword = userSnapshot.Value.ToString();

  if (storedID == id && storedPassword == password) {
    loginSuccess = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(loginSuccess)
{
    //Load next scene
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Incorrect user details");
}
```

Comment: the RoomList is already been added to the build settings and made the suggestion you said but still not going to the scene.

Comment: When debugging how far down the code do you get debug messages?

Comment: until "Connected to Firebase database"

Comment: In the Editor console you do have the errors toggled visible yes? Also add some Debugs in the try method between the different tasks to see where it's failing if it is, after `DatabaseReference usersRef` for example

Comment: I added 
DatabaseReference usersRef = databaseReference.Child("Users").Child("Monitoring");

            Debug.Log("Before getting value from Firebase database");

            usersRef.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Inside GetValueAsync continuation");

got both of them in my console and the debug "Login successfully"

Comment: Does that mean it's working now? if not have you changed the timescale anywhere?

Comment: it's still not working, It's not calling properly the StartCoroutine(LoadNextSceneWithDelay(3f)); because I added a debug after that and it's not showing

Comment: But you said you got the success login message which is after it?

Comment: sorry I didn't realize that I putted the login successfully before coroutine now after I put it back after coroutine its not showing now.

Comment: What happens if you try changing the scene without the delay coroutine?

Comment: still not going to the other scene, I tried making new script dedicated for going to the other scene for testing if all my scene is working properly and it's all working.

Comment: If you add a Debug message in the `LoadNextSceneWithDelay` method before the delay is it printed to the console?

Comment: no its not showing